# Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to create new bundle in symfony but I am getting this error

> Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied

I am using Mac OS and vagrant to run my symfony project.

How I can get rid of this problem?

Comment: make sure you've set the right permissions

Comment: Isn't it pretty obvious what the issue is from the error message? :o You need RW permissions, which you don't have in the set directory

Comment: Yep, something about permissions, but it may not be what you think. In my case I had put composer in a docker container, and of course the full path that `symfony new` passed to `composer create-project` doesn't exist in there. I've fixed my container's mounts to match the exact PWD and CWD on the host. Error gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to find out which user your web-server runs under. This can vary from `www-data`, `fpm`, `apache`, `http`, etc. One, rather painless, way (but not % accurate) is from `Symfony`'s docs:

```
echo $(ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1)
```

Once you find out that piece of info, you need to configure permissions to parent directory in which you wanted to run `mkdir()`.

You can either alter ownership of directory:

```
chown -R <user>:<user> <parent-directory>
chmod -R 664 <parent-directory>
```

This will set ownership of directory to user and change permissions to `RW` to owner and group.

Another strategy, would be to find out if group is allowed to `RW` to parent directory and then add web user to that group, but it really depends on your preferences if you want to do it this way.

Hope this helps...